# Scope value is Undefined within $modal popup function as an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-controller

I've the scenario where I'm using $uibModal popup to add a new record, where I'm passing the scope object into the function to get it saved, but I'm getting the result as 'undefined' and my code is below along with the [plunker] (http://plnkr.co/edit/WXKCyzlfJFCA3FB7S2pa?p=preview) link.

```
  $scope.userList=[];
  $scope.addUser = function(){
    $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: 'userData.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
    });
  };
  $scope.addNewUser=function(user){
    console.log(user);
    $scope.userList.push({
      'id': user.id,
      'name': user.name,
      'age': user.age,
      'gender': user.gender
    });
    $scope.clearUserArea(user);
  };
  $scope.clearUserArea = function(user){
    console.log(user);
    user.id='';
    user.name='';
    user.age='';
    user.gender='';
  };
```

Please let me know where I'm wrong with this code. And also please refer my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WXKCyzlfJFCA3FB7S2pa?p=preview) link for further code on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had misspelled in `ng-modal` . it should be `ng-model` instead of `ng-modal`.

Comment: Oh my bad. Thanks @Ramesh Rajendran.